# FileHashMap<K, V>: Reuse the same hashmap

Tags: java, file, dictionary, hashmap

```
   FileHashMap<int, String> myMap = new FileHashMap<int, String>("/myFile");       
   myMap.put(1, "First");
   myMap.put(2, "Second");
   myMap.save();
   myMap.close();
```

According to my understanding this code will save the Hashmap files on to disk... But when I am creating the object of FileHashMap again, like this:

```
    FileHashMap<int, String> myMap = new FileHashMap<int, String>("/myFile");       
    if(myMap.containsKey(1){
    System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("No");
    }
```

This is giving the output as "No".. I want to reuse the file, reuse the Hashmap... How can I do this.. Can anybody explain??

Comment: What library is FileHashMap from? It's not out of the Java libraries... Also this can't be valid as you can't have `int` as a generic type parameter. This doesn't seem half-realistic.

Comment: From when Collections accepting the primitives as type parameters ?

Comment: (Ignoring the generics issue) See the FileHashMap documentation - perhaps it doesn't support restoring from an existing file; or perhaps it requires another constructor (e.g. with a flag) be used; or perhaps the file was never flushed/written in the previous program; or ..

Comment: Looking at the docs at http://software.clapper.org/javautil/api/org/clapper/util/misc/FileHashMap.html, it looks like (aside from the invalid generic type) your code should work.

Comment: Also missing a parenthesis. Is this actual compiling, working code that demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem: the [API](http://software.clapper.org/javautil/api/org/clapper/util/misc/FileHashMap.html) is confusing. It says that "[a] FileHashMap is persistent by default," but the zero- and one-arg constructors (the one you're using which specifies the file name is the one-arg) create a new *transient* `FileHashMap` — that is, the file is deleted after the `FileHashMap` is closed. The two-arg constructor takes the filename and an `int` options flag, but there's no specific option for "persistent", so you just have to make sure the flag is not "transient" (to be precise, `flags & FileHashMap.TRANSIENT == 0`).

In order to get it to save and open the file, pass `0` as the flag to the constructor (unless you want other options — read the docs) as such:

```
new FileHashMap<Integer, String>(fileName, 0);
```

Note that the generic parameter needs to be `Integer` rather than `int`, as comments have stated. Also note that you probably want your file path to be something other than "/myFile" as that will most likely give you a permission denied error, unless you're running as root, which you probably shouldn't be.